# Converting csv file to xlsx

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to make some script which will automatically when it is called convert csv files into xlsx files. I was trying by python script. I have little problem with delimiter cause I need to put two delimters : tab and comma

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

files = ['test3.csv']

for i in files:
    workbook = Workbook(i + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
with open('test3.csv') as f:
        reader=csv.reader((f), delimiter=",")
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
workbook.close()
```

This code is ok, but I need to put inside delimiter also condition "\t" ?
Does anyone knows how?

Comment: What did you try in Python and why didn't it work? Similarly, what about your php script isn't working?

Comment: Have a look at the [xlswriter tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter).

Comment: Exel will open CSV files, is your inital CSV malformed (sounds like it may not be CSV) and you are trying to convert it to TAB delimited?

Comment: Incredible how a question can totally change in the space of a month from one using PHP code to one using Python code

Answer (score 3):

The Writer is `Excel2007` not `XLSX`, so that's the value that you pass to createWriter to tell it which Writer you want to use; and OfficeOpenXML format files don't have delimiters or enclosures, so there's no Writer method for setting these in the Excel2007 Writer

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$csv = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("test.csv");
$writer= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($csv, 'Excel2007');
$writer->save("test.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7528-PHP-Convert-CSV-files-to-Excel-using-PHPExcel-library.html), maybe it can help

```
<?php 
/** 
 * CSVToExcelConverter 
 */ 
class CSVToExcelConverter 
{ 
    /** 
     * Read given csv file and write all rows to given xls file 
     *  
     * @param string $csv_file Resource path of the csv file 
     * @param string $xls_file Resource path of the excel file 
     * @param string $csv_enc Encoding of the csv file, use utf8 if null 
     * @throws Exception 
     */ 
    public static function convert($csv_file, $xls_file, $csv_enc=null) { 
        //set cache 
        $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp; 
        PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod); 

        //open csv file 
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV(); 
        if ($csv_enc != null) 
            $objReader->setInputEncoding($csv_enc); 
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($csv_file); 
        $in_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); 

        //open excel file 
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
        $out_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(); 

        //row index start from 1 
        $row_index = 0; 
        foreach ($in_sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) { 
            $row_index++; 
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator(); 
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 

            //column index start from 0 
            $column_index = -1; 
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) { 
                // put up your delimiter or cell formatting here
                $column_index++; 
                $out_sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column_index, $row_index, $cell->getValue()); 
            } 
        } 

        //write excel file 
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
        $objWriter->save($xls_file); 
    } 
}
```

and here is how you can use it:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{ 
?> 
<html> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Convert CSV to XLSX</h1> 
        <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input type="file" name="file"/> 
            <input type="submit"/> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html> 
<?php 
    exit; 
} 

//obtain PHPExcel from http://phpexcel.codeplex.com 
require_once('PHPExcel.php'); 
require_once('CSVToExcelConverter.php'); 

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
{ 
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"]; 
    exit; 
} 

try 
{ 
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.'test.xlsx'); 

    CSVToExcelConverter::convert($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'php://output'); 
} catch(Exception $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: I saw this solution, but will he format my csv as I want? Where I can put delimiters that I want?

Comment: look at code `$column_index = -1; foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) { $column_index++; $out_sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column_index, $row_index, $cell->getValue()); } ` where you could put up a delimiter